# Opendaylight Oxygen Error when instantiating bean osgiBundleScanningSchema

Tags: java, apache-karaf, opendaylight, blueprint

I use ODL Oxygen 0.8.1 version. I have blueprint.xml file like that

```
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
  xmlns:odl="http://opendaylight.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
  odl:use-default-for-reference-types="true">

  <reference id="dataBroker"
    interface="org.opendaylight.controller.md.sal.binding.api.DataBroker"
    odl:type="default" />

 <service ref="cliCommandsImpl" interface="tr.com.argela.cliapp.cli.api.CliappCliCommands" />
  <bean id="cliCommandsImpl" class="tr.com.argela.cliapp.cli.impl.CliappCliCommandsImpl">
    <argument ref="dataBroker" />
  </bean>

  <command-bundle xmlns="http://karaf.apache.org/xmlns/shell/v1.0.0">
     <command name="nelmo/test-command2">
        <action class="tr.com.argela.cliapp.cli.commands.CliappCliShowCommand">
        </action>
    </command>
  </command-bundle>

</blueprint>
```

I couldnt instantiate the bean "CliappCliCommandsImpl", logs are following

Caused by: org.osgi.service.blueprint.container.ComponentDefinitionException: Error when instantiating bean osgiBundleScanningSchema of class org.opendaylight.mdsal.dom.schema.service.osgi.OsgiBundleScanningSchemaService
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.wrapAsCompDefEx(BeanRecipe.java:361) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.getInstanceFromStaticFactory(BeanRecipe.java:331) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.getInstance(BeanRecipe.java:280) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate2(BeanRecipe.java:830) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate(BeanRecipe.java:811) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe$1.call(AbstractRecipe.java:79) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:88) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.RefRecipe.internalCreate(RefRecipe.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:106) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.ServiceRecipe.createService(ServiceRecipe.java:285) ~[?:?]

Answer (score 0):

I clear data directory of karaf then restart. Everthing seems normal.